# Does rails automatically call javascript files that have the name of the action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If inside a view folder, you have a .js.erb file named after an action, does Rails automatically run that file when that particular action is called?

For example, if you have a file called create.js.erb inside the views/comments folder, will this file run when the create action in the comments controller is run?

Answer (score 1):

Only if the request is an Ajax request and you're handling it with a respond :to block for JS. If it's a straight up HTML request, the controller will look for a .html.erb file named create.

Comment: Actually it will never *run* the JS file. It will serve it as to the browser and the browser then decides what to do with it. Rails will *never* execute a JavaScript file on the server.